# Google Pagerank (PR) History and Next Upcoming Updates

Tags: google, pagerank, google-algorithm

As you may know Google updates PageRank roughly 4 times a year, out of interest and not for ranking purposes I often check when the next incoming update is. I do this by searching various sites and finding out the history, Well since I'm a regular on Pro Webmasters I thought I'd ask the question and provide the answer for myself and others webmasters alike.

So the question is simple, what is the last updates and when we can expect another Google Page Rank (PR) Update.

UPDATE: Still no Google Pagerank update yet - very late.

Comment: This doesn't quite fall under "website you control" as stated in the [faq]

Answer (score 0):

### Google PageRank (PR) updates (2014).

*UPCOMING UPDATES*

Assuming that Google reverts back to using regular updates of it's page rank then we can expect to see something like these estimates:

- March - April 2014
- July - August 2014
- November - December 2014

Last year in 2013 Google actually took 10 months to roll out a new pagerank update, this was 4th Feb to 6 Dec, if this is the case for 2014 then another update could be as late as October 2014!

---

**Google PR dates for the past few years**

*Google PageRank (PR) Updates in the Year 2013*

- 4th February 2013
- 6th December 2013

*Google PageRank (PR) Updates in the Year 2012*

- 7th February
- 2nd May
- 2nd August
- 7th November

*Google PageRank (PR) Updates in the Year 2011*

- 20th January
- 27th June
- 8th November

*Google PageRank (PR) Updates in the Year 2010*

- 3rd April

*Google PageRank (PR) Updates in the Year 2009*

- 1st April
- 27th May
- 25th June
- October 30th
- December 2009

*Google PageRank (PR) Updates in the Year 2008*

- 29th February
- 30th April
- 25th July
- 26th September
- 31st December

*Google PageRank (PR) Updates in the Year 2007*

- 10th January
- 25th January
- 30th April
- 28th October
- 12th December

*Google PageRank (PR) Updates in the Year 2006*

- 4th January
- 30th January
- 18th February
- 4th April
- 7th April
- 27th May
- 30th July
- 28th September

*Google PageRank (PR) Updates in the Year 2005*

- 1st January
- 15th July
- 15th October

*Google PageRank (PR) Updates in the Year 2004*

- 1st January
- *1st February*
- 16th March
- 7th April
- 23rd April
- 31st May
- 2nd June
- 6th October

Resources For/About Google PageRank

- [Google Webmaster Help (Matt Cutts) How does PageRank Work?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3Jup5R1MGY)
- [Google PageRank (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank)
- [Google's PageRank U.S. Patent 6,285,999](http://www.google.com/patents/US6285999)
- [Google Toolbar](http://www.google.com/toolbar/ie/index.html)