# How to retrieve PageRank for a blogger blog?

Tags: url, subdomain, pagerank, blogger

I know this sounds like a stupid/obvious question, but when I try to retrieve the page rank of my blog using online tools, I don't get any result.

My blog is know as http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.nl/, and has a subdomain URL pointing to it: http://technotes.tostaky.biz/.

Is there any way I can retrieve the PageRank for my blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many online pagerank checkers use cached results and therefor the results can be old or you may even find that your site is not listed.

**Use a ToolBar**

You should use a toolbar for your browser to view real time page ranks, here's a few:

- [Internet Explorer](http://www.google.com/intl/en/toolbar/ie/index.html)
- [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/pagerank/contribute/roadblock/?src=dp-btn-primary&version=2.0)
- [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pagerank-status/hbdkkfheckcdppiaiabobmennhijkknn?hl=en)

**Pagerank for technotes.tostaky.biz**

The current pagerank on the front page for technotes.tostaky.biz is PR0, we are currentlying awaiting a new page rank from Google shortly.. To view the estimated dates of the PR updates from Google go here: [Google Rank Page, Next upcoming updates..](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47577/google-pagerank-pr-history-and-next-upcoming-updates)