# Why is the PageRank for my website listed as "unavailable" in this tool?

Tags: seo, google-search, pagerank

I usually check my site up at SEO Site Checkup. Now, my site isn't top-notch, and I don't expect it to have a high PageRank, but  SEO Site Checkup says the PageRank is **unavailable** for my site (that's different from a PageRank of 0 or 2...).

What does "unavailable" mean in this case, and how do I achieve a PageRank number?

Here's a screenshot:

[image: SEO Site Checkup says my site's PR is unavailable]

By the Way: My sitemaps have been submitted to Google, I didn't receive any messages in Webmaster Tools, and my webpages have been indexed by Googlebot.

If you search `site:example.com` in Google for example, you get results from my site, meaning that my site is indexed. It's just that it never appears in real, natural searches (not `site:` based ones), and my PageRank is listed as "`unavailable`".

Comment: All the tools that queried Google for pagerank quit working a long time ago as Google quit making it available. Don't know where this is supposedly deriving it from, but it ain't Google so it's likely road apples found on a full-moon lit night at a crossroads at midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means *that tool* is unable to find *PageRank* for *your homepage*. That is literally all it means.

- [PageRank is *per web page* not per website](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3494/are-page-ranks-for-subdomains-independent/3495#3495). So all that tool claims to report is it can't find what the PR is for your homepage.
- That tool is *not* Google so anything it claims to report cannot be assured as accurate. Google does not offer an API for determining a page's PageRank so however they are trying to determine your homepage's PageRank it is done through means that cannot be considered reliable. So your homepage may have PageRank assigned to it but that tool cannot find what it is.
- [PageRank is not often publicly updated anymore](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47577/google-pagerank-pr-history-and-next-upcoming-updates) so your homepage may have PageRank but no tool can tell you what it is since Google hasn't made that information available. So you may have PageRank and Google may be using it to help rank your pages but you don't know how much it is and won't know until they do a public update again.
- PageRank has little (and possibly no) SEO value anymore. It used to be important in Google's ranking algorithm but that was a long time ago. Their ranking algorithm has become much more sophisticated and simply relying on a numerical representation of link popularity just isn't necessary (or accurate). You've spent more time researching this then it is worth. Don't chase PageRank. It is obsolete and not useful for you to spend *any* time on.

Comment: Now I realize this :D I finally found out that Google's ranking algorithms are much more than PR. Thanks so much John Conde!